# how to copy an integer from one array to another in mips

Tags: arrays, copy, mips

I had a project that I had to fill an integer array from the console. now I have to copy that array to another

but when I print both arrays I get the numbers from array a  correct and from array b only zeroes, so I think the code that copies the elements is not working good.

Can somebody help me with that part ? :)

```
load_array:
la $18,a   #i load again the address of a array
j copy_array

copy_array:  #for 
beq $22,$16,exit  #if j==i, exit

lb $2, 0($18)
add $17,$2,$0  #add it to array
sw $17, 0($21) #save it $17

addi $21,$21,4 #change array

bne $22,$16,next #if i!=5, go to next

next:
addi $22,$22,1 #j++
j copy_array  #jumb to first loop
```

$18 = array a,  $22=0, j,   $16=i <-size of the array a,   $21= array b

if somebody needs more code from me, I will post it :)

Comment: What's up with all the numeric registers? What's wrong with the names? (e.g. `$t0`, `$s0`, etc)

Comment: I'm sorry but I did change all the numeric registers into $t0 etc but my code in some points stopped working properly.

So is it bad to leave them like that ?
Cause changing them didn't make my code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only increment $21 but miss incrementing $18 so lb $2, 0($18) will take the first element of a on each iteration.

Comment: I added "addi $18,$18,4" but I'm still getting zeroes. :/

Comment: I found what was wrong in my code and your answer helped! thank you :)

problem solved!